# How to make source code of a user-defined function in global environment inaccessible in R? (for education purposes)

Tags: r, user-defined-functions

I'm a molecular biology instructor, and since the schools have turned online, I was forced to find a way to keep conducting "experiments". I've decided to conduct my "experiments" in R because the kids can already use it.

I have written a function that simulates data by using certain numbers, numbers which the students will be asked to calculate by using the output.

I plan to provide them the function as a global environment object. However, I don't want them to jump to the source code by using `getAnywhere()` function, and see the numbers there and simply copy + paste stuff. Is there a way I can make the source code of my user-defined function inaccessible? I know hiding code is not cool, but I will do it for the sake of online teaching. If there's no way, then I will try to find another solution.

Comment: There's no way to do this. You can make it more difficult to get the code, but it will always be possible to get the R code of any function that's run in your R session. If R needs to run the code it needs to be able to see the code. One alternative would be to move "private" logic to a server and have the package make API calls to the server

Comment: I concur 100%. I researched this very question several years ago, and the answers I found all said "cannot be done". One can try to make it obscure (R6, for instance, though using it for this purpose is grossly mis-shaping its intent), but there will always be ways to see the code. The closest I got to doing this was *"compile C/C++ code into a shared-object and link to it"*; this can use `Rcpp` and such, and only distribute the binary (not source) package to the students. I suspect that that level of obscuration (imperfect as it is) might suffice for your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies. I see. I will re-design my questions accordingly.

Comment: @r2evans I think you could get reasonable obscuration directly in R. I think most students wouldn't get far with a function obscured as below, though I've never taught an R class - maybe you'd have a better idea how well this would work in the real world?

Comment: From a "paranoid" standpoint, there's always one student who shows a little initiative, and perhaps even gets advice from somebody on SO (in response to a question) and then spreads it to the students. It doesn't happen every semester, but once the gouge is out there, there is no hiding the function's contents. "Gouge" persists. Having said that, I'm really intrigued by your answer, it has a lot of merit! Mucho kudos to you!

Comment: A bit out of scope and technical but one way to manage this is to create an API with ‘plumber‘ package. Obviously you need to be able to host it on a server or ship it via docker so it requires some specific technical knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

I guess if this is for educational purposes, then a reasonable attempt at obscuration should be good enough. Here is a function that will take any other function as an argument and return a function with identical behaviour but whose code is not human readable:

```r
obscure <- function(func) {
  f <- as.character(body(func))
  r <- charToRaw(paste(paste(f, collapse = "\n"), "}", sep = "\n"))
  bod <- as.call(list(quote(eval), as.call(list(quote(parse), 
                      text = as.call(list(quote(eval), 
                             as.call(list(quote(rawToChar), r))))))))
  as.function(c(formals(func), bod))
}
```

So, let's say you wanted to obscure a closed-form Fibonacci generator:

```r
fib <- function(n) {
  round(((5 + sqrt(5)) / 10) * (( 1 + sqrt(5)) / 2) ** (1:n - 1))
}

fib(10)
#> [1]  1  1  2  3  5  8 13 21 34 55
```

All you need to do is:

```r
fib <- obscure(fib)
fib(10)
#> [1]  1  1  2  3  5  8 13 21 34 55
```

But if you look at the function itself, it now looks like this:

```r
fib
#> function (n) 
#> eval(parse(text = eval(rawToChar(as.raw(c(0x7b, 0x0a, 0x72, 0x6f, 
#> 0x75, 0x6e, 0x64, 0x28, 0x28, 0x28, 0x35, 0x20, 0x2b, 0x20, 0x73, 
#> 0x71, 0x72, 0x74, 0x28, 0x35, 0x29, 0x29, 0x2f, 0x31, 0x30, 0x29, 
#> 0x20, 0x2a, 0x20, 0x28, 0x28, 0x31, 0x20, 0x2b, 0x20, 0x73, 0x71, 
#> 0x72, 0x74, 0x28, 0x35, 0x29, 0x29, 0x2f, 0x32, 0x29, 0x5e, 0x28, 
#> 0x31, 0x3a, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x2d, 0x20, 0x31, 0x29, 0x29, 0x0a, 0x7d
#> ))))))
#> <environment: 0x0000025b9f7dc068>
```

Of course, an advanced user would likely be able to reverse-engineer this in a couple of minutes, but if you are teaching an R class I'm guessing most students will see this and give up.

Comment: I'm intrigued by this ... I think you're correct, most will not know how to rev-engr this. While you and I know how to instantly (and trivially) reverse it (it takes one simple command), I'd think this will work up until one enterprising student figures it out and the word gets out.

Comment: I have used this and it worked! So thank you very much, Allan. How can I reverse this btw? How can I see the source code again? One of my functions did not work and I need to reach the source code now, and I did not save it somewhere before I run this code =) It even got me.

Comment: Ah ha! That's a good measure of success! You can reverse the example with `body(fib) <- eval(body(fib)[[2]])` . Obviously just change `fib` to whatever your function name is. Let me know when you have saved this line somewhere - I should probably delete this comment.

Comment: Thank you, Allan =) Yes, I guess that's a measure success =) We can keep the messages. The kids have submitted their assignments and they loved it. Thank you very much once again for offering help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method that will be a pain to reverse. It uses the [`walkast` package](https://github.com/TobCap/walkast) to obfuscate function calls.

Essentially, it replaces `f(x)` with `{randomstring <- f; randomNumber randomOperator randomNumber; randomstring(x)}`

Modify the `min` and `max` in `runif(1, min = 0, max = 1)` so that it is in the range of your secret numbers.

```
obfuscate <- function(f) {
  result <- f
  
  body(result) <- walkast::walk_ast(
    body(result),
    walkast::make_visitor(
      hd = function(f) {
        new_name <- as.name(paste0("x", runif(1, 0, 100000000)))
        decoy_f <- as.name(sample(c("+", "-", "*", "/", "%%", "%*%"), 1))
        bquote({
          .(new_name) <- .(f)
          .(decoy_f)(.(runif(1, min = 0, max = 1)), .(runif(1, min = 0, max = 1)))
          .(new_name)
        })
      }
    )
  )
  result
}


fib <- function(n) {
  round(((5 + sqrt(5)) / 10) * (( 1 + sqrt(5)) / 2) ** (1:n - 1))
}
```

`obfuscate(fib)` results in the following function (which isn't too hard to reverse).

```
function (n) 
{
    x67911473.8479257 <- `{`
    0.130855958675966%%0.881266586482525
    x67911473.8479257
}({
    x76250116.8530434 <- round
    0.302100569708273 - 0.405373327899724
    x76250116.8530434
}({
    x82210419.5132852 <- `*`
    0.49425036739558 + 0.228636586572975
    x82210419.5132852
}({
    x15765817.3236996 <- `(`
    0.797338604461402 %*% 0.514307061443105
    x15765817.3236996
}({
    x71525579.597801 <- `/`
    0.909275721525773 %*% 0.446680159773678
    x71525579.597801
}({
    x30879483.6513698 <- `(`
    0.383802859345451%%0.83112145261839
    x30879483.6513698
}({
    x27604046.7899293 <- `+`
    0.876430705189705/0.856748269638047
    x27604046.7899293
}(5, {
    x73314726.5156731 <- sqrt
    0.708666266873479/0.336862851632759
    x73314726.5156731
}(5))), 10)), {
    x70590986.6606817 <- `^`
    0.566703328397125%%0.671325634233654
    x70590986.6606817
}({
    x24871017.2018036 <- `(`
    0.0474121794104576 + 0.763756504980847
    x24871017.2018036
}({
    x88098038.5933071 <- `/`
    0.328246646560729 + 0.514381068525836
    x88098038.5933071
}({
    x36233226.7919555 <- `(`
    0.000577503815293312/0.30069664795883
    x36233226.7919555
}({
    x96489506.5175369 <- `+`
    0.836315712891519%%0.218373921466991
    x96489506.5175369
}(1, {
    x65204835.5899751 <- sqrt
    0.546689067035913/0.838512626476586
    x65204835.5899751
}(5))), 2)), {
    x41097439.0804768 <- `(`
    0.318402596283704 + 0.181835192954168
    x41097439.0804768
}({
    x14225565.2230233 <- `-`
    0.0201902554836124 - 0.763278516940773
    x14225565.2230233
}({
    x67021324.7649372 <- `:`
    0.603728511603549/0.995236924383789
    x67021324.7649372
}(1, n), 1))))))
```

However, `obfuscate` can be called multiple times. `obfuscate(obfuscate(fib))` results in the following

```
function (n) 
{
    x13820952.9686719 <- {
        x14231921.8954071 <- `{`
        0.964784309733659 - 0.318950723856688
        x14231921.8954071
    }({
        x98483844.473958 <- `<-`
        0.499919829424471 %*% 0.25088473292999
        x98483844.473958
    }(x77140931.5057099, `{`), {
        x71807632.4323192 <- `+`
        0.704186083516106 + 0.909325393149629
        x71807632.4323192
    }(0.508911525830626, 0.712898454861715), x77140931.5057099)
    0.915209622122347 + 0.290264912880957
    x13820952.9686719
}({
    x34399270.1265961 <- {
        x98775665.2990356 <- `{`
        0.581808406859636 %*% 0.577146121067926
        x98775665.2990356
    }({
        x72328119.2127615 <- `<-`
        0.989937041886151 %*% 0.646907166577876
        x72328119.2127615
    }(x52481220.1270834, round), {
        x6828759.70378518 <- `%*%`
        0.27078406792134/0.295143382623792
        x6828759.70378518
    }(0.801469809608534, 0.987752696499228), x52481220.1270834)
    0.922306241467595 - 0.56200037105009
    x34399270.1265961
}({
    x94231348.6244529 <- {
        x57375249.103643 <- `{`
        0.72766156680882 * 0.781972301891074
        x57375249.103643
    }({
        x3551404.13157642 <- `<-`
        0.0673318353947252%%0.513684156117961
        x3551404.13157642
    }(x3026251.47160143, `*`), {
        x12980086.7522135 <- `*`
        0.215703511377797 + 0.520233752438799
        x12980086.7522135
    }(0.569129609037191, 0.133742173202336), x3026251.47160143)
    0.510110176866874 - 0.0307286188472062
    x94231348.6244529
}({
    x89750883.4721521 <- {
        x600093.929097056 <- `{`
        0.321572621352971 %*% 0.0427047829143703
        x600093.929097056
    }({
        x71001436.9338751 <- `<-`
        0.771520792506635 %*% 0.772518398938701
        x71001436.9338751
    }(x25210925.8202836, `(`), {
        x68944892.520085 <- `*`
        0.268720921361819 %*% 0.425112737575546
        x68944892.520085
    }(0.52520202845335, 0.656426891451702), x25210925.8202836)
    0.47237404435873 * 0.495256265625358
    x89750883.4721521
}({
    x71292330.3479329 <- {
        x51233950.9557933 <- `{`
        0.357416934100911/0.0655053614173084
        x51233950.9557933
    }({
        x30669082.3053941 <- `<-`
        0.534916127100587 + 0.67862187908031
        x30669082.3053941
    }(x47235390.8233345, `/`), {
        x15582043.2817563 <- `/`
        0.873394214781001 * 0.931123967515305
        x15582043.2817563
    }(0.986741927452385, 0.742083500837907), x47235390.8233345)
    0.15898777008988%%0.68169358978048
    x71292330.3479329
}({
    x32579387.0491907 <- {
        x73828555.5504262 <- `{`
        0.978108135983348 - 0.102359032956883
        x73828555.5504262
    }({
        x49107574.8577714 <- `<-`
        0.7187738600187/0.428680357057601
        x49107574.8577714
    }(x57762583.6245716, `(`), {
        x57358532.4920714 <- `*`
        0.178639843361452 * 0.673680510604754
        x57358532.4920714
    }(0.204503980930895, 0.0359067062381655), x57762583.6245716)
    0.0257267474662513/0.612508951220661
    x32579387.0491907
}({
    x96714596.9159901 <- {
        x11374640.2319521 <- `{`
        0.0720340947154909 + 0.944227180676535
        x11374640.2319521
    }({
        x62696768.6694115 <- `<-`
        0.639268048806116%%0.525764014804736
        x62696768.6694115
    }(x76306633.4184259, `+`), {
        x42795905.0051868 <- `+`
        0.94626947841607 + 0.515851546544582
        x42795905.0051868
    }(0.904065714450553, 0.583518052240834), x76306633.4184259)
    0.604620382655412 * 0.631076122168452
    x96714596.9159901
}(5, {
    x83315562.5732616 <- {
        x83753042.9475009 <- `{`
        0.349399645114318 + 0.651053918525577
        x83753042.9475009
    }({
        x69223746.0520118 <- `<-`
        0.29312734818086 * 0.881964908912778
        x69223746.0520118
    }(x73975120.1821491, sqrt), {
        x67292128.5731718 <- `+`
        0.480338253779337 - 0.482176560908556
        x67292128.5731718
    }(0.601392406970263, 0.380848217988387), x73975120.1821491)
    0.0832952118944377 + 0.0914795149583369
    x83315562.5732616
}(5))), 10)), {
    x98729057.8894317 <- {
        x77170495.1068386 <- `{`
        0.227124285651371/0.278982728952542
        x77170495.1068386
    }({
        x48747039.726004 <- `<-`
        0.782126144738868 * 0.675149171613157
        x48747039.726004
    }(x89894129.1496158, `^`), {
        x96451648.7671062 <- `%%`
        0.715406887698919 %*% 0.282268565380946
        x96451648.7671062
    }(0.27587090106681, 0.145314523251727), x89894129.1496158)
    0.381198771763593%%0.307774103712291
    x98729057.8894317
}({
    x97305397.3633796 <- {
        x70868420.926854 <- `{`
        0.277484080987051 + 0.973759955028072
        x70868420.926854
    }({
        x72545721.4051858 <- `<-`
        0.50800796574913 * 0.856975607108325
        x72545721.4051858
    }(x33412416.2793159, `(`), {
        x20543128.5547093 <- `*`
        0.219559877878055%%0.570555842481554
        x20543128.5547093
    }(0.106497411616147, 0.345936729339883), x33412416.2793159)
    0.706679665949196 * 0.461514561669901
    x97305397.3633796
}({
    x92932011.8622854 <- {
        x25150360.353291 <- `{`
        0.945939902681857 + 0.0913955171126872
        x25150360.353291
    }({
        x31840611.0163778 <- `<-`
        0.00124536827206612 * 0.692353655351326
        x31840611.0163778
    }(x61161323.3806565, `/`), {
        x63229239.1266674 <- `%*%`
        0.56810829625465%%0.350754451937973
        x63229239.1266674
    }(0.266102685593069, 0.217837403062731), x61161323.3806565)
    0.544797678478062 * 0.0696846419014037
    x92932011.8622854
}({
    x72556719.5564508 <- {
        x2918882.92413205 <- `{`
        0.382788195740432%%0.233721876982599
        x2918882.92413205
    }({
        x1332410.1222679 <- `<-`
        0.121992226224393 + 0.0637996080331504
        x1332410.1222679
    }(x88590273.0282396, `(`), {
        x84656940.9128278 <- `*`
        0.363471970660612 * 0.967681086389348
        x84656940.9128278
    }(0.47135023586452, 0.495704435743392), x88590273.0282396)
    0.802222049562261 %*% 0.314430670579895
    x72556719.5564508
}({
    x33861630.6427866 <- {
        x7418637.51318306 <- `{`
        0.00906742154620588%%0.331271679606289
        x7418637.51318306
    }({
        x69295283.2672745 <- `<-`
        0.00934437615796924 %*% 0.161317143123597
        x69295283.2672745
    }(x49074813.9331117, `+`), {
        x42538731.6150591 <- `*`
        0.713973646285012/0.187995387706906
        x42538731.6150591
    }(0.276253602933139, 0.325099671958014), x49074813.9331117)
    0.527837971923873 * 0.880572498776019
    x33861630.6427866
}(1, {
    x77607083.4835991 <- {
        x68655005.4699183 <- `{`
        0.858293377095833%%0.16589346411638
        x68655005.4699183
    }({
        x20779904.4670537 <- `<-`
        0.0172271258197725 - 0.85583262424916
        x20779904.4670537
    }(x63671239.4887581, sqrt), {
        x92613451.6252205 <- `%*%`
        0.921735821058974 + 0.557587723247707
        x92613451.6252205
    }(0.53566943667829, 0.865151737350971), x63671239.4887581)
    0.357367471093312 * 0.977310829563066
    x77607083.4835991
}(5))), 2)), {
    x48921614.093706 <- {
        x57634989.1722202 <- `{`
        0.408984839916229 + 0.219921594019979
        x57634989.1722202
    }({
        x20686308.6903468 <- `<-`
        0.87269201874733 * 0.290828781668097
        x20686308.6903468
    }(x31356643.6292604, `(`), {
        x54914335.5572596 <- `/`
        0.42553190421313 * 0.873098325682804
        x54914335.5572596
    }(0.809229557868093, 0.487828205805272), x31356643.6292604)
    0.903046790510416%%0.475023675011471
    x48921614.093706
}({
    x46909810.5793819 <- {
        x71135967.9931775 <- `{`
        0.534440700896084 - 0.723820263287053
        x71135967.9931775
    }({
        x40692157.0654958 <- `<-`
        0.809898991836235 * 0.154304394498467
        x40692157.0654958
    }(x25574955.6235969, `-`), {
        x87320719.3100825 <- `-`
        0.171987064182758 * 0.565342281479388
        x87320719.3100825
    }(0.353071014164016, 0.349617956206203), x25574955.6235969)
    0.145128468051553 + 0.605287740007043
    x46909810.5793819
}({
    x76092396.4902759 <- {
        x33732652.5477692 <- `{`
        0.427568282932043/0.671309909550473
        x33732652.5477692
    }({
        x17347284.3598574 <- `<-`
        0.135752162430435%%0.060178006067872
        x17347284.3598574
    }(x64530064.5381212, `:`), {
        x49644516.8508217 <- `%*%`
        0.75615629600361 * 0.157231835182756
        x49644516.8508217
    }(0.353608228033409, 0.409501505084336), x64530064.5381212)
    0.827440596884117 - 0.0416028220206499
    x76092396.4902759
}(1, n), 1))))))
```

You can call `obfuscate` arbitrarily many times. Calling it 4 times results in over 4k lines of code

```
f <- fib
for (i in 1:4) {
  f <- obfuscate(f)
}
length(readLines(textConnection(as.character(body(f)))))
#> 4354
```

Comment: Nice! It took me a while to get my head round this. It would take me a while to reverse engineer a function that has been put through this a few times, and it would certainly be harder than any actual problem you would give to students. I reckon this could do the trick  +1

Comment: Trying to decipher this would cost them a lot of time, which they don't have (hopefully). Thank you very much, people! Now I can focus on making my research question better.